# passing structure to function in c language

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, function-declaration

can anyone help? why '&' is not required while calling a function in this program? but is thought that '&' is required in call by reference.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void traversal(struct node *ptr)
{
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *second;
    struct node *third;

    head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 7;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 5;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 12;
    third->next = NULL;

    traversal(head);

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone help? why '&' is not required while calling a function in this program? but is thought that '&' is required in call by reference.

Comment: Because `head` is already a pointer, to the `struct` that was allocated dynamically.

Comment: There's no "pass-by-reference" in C. You pass references (pointers) by value.

Comment: Also, casting the result of `malloc` is not needed in C. The pointer conversion from `void*`  is implicit. (The cast *would* be needed in C++, but there you shouldn't use `malloc` anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a singly linked list where nodes are linked by pointers.

The function `traversal` does not accept an object of the type `struct node`. It accepts a pointer to an object of the type `struct node *`.

```
void traversal(struct node *ptr)
{
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
ptr = ptr->next;
}
}
```

As the original pointer used as an argument expression is not changed within the function then there is no any sense to pass it to the function by reference through a pointer to it.

Dereferencing pointers within the function as for example

```
ptr->data
```

the function has a direct access to data members of nodes pointed to by pointers.

That is is the object of the type `struct node` that is indeed is passed by reference to the function through a pointer to it. But the pointer itself is passed by value.

To make it clear consider the following simple demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *px )
{
    printf( "x = %d\n", *px );
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;

    int *px = &x;

    f( px );
}
```

As you can see to output the value of the variable `x` declared in `main` within the function `f` using the pointer `px` to `x` there is no need to pass the pointer itself by reference through a pointer to it. However the object `x` is passed to the function by reference indirectly through the pointer `px`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't get caught in the [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) trap, where you see a pattern and apply it without understanding the semantics and why or when the pattern is appropriate.

In this case the requirement is *not* to blindly apply an `&` to all *pass-by-reference* calls.  The requirement is merely to pass a reference.  In this case a `struct node*`.  If you have a `struct node` object, the *address of* operator (`&`) yields a `struct node*`.  However in your case `head` is already a `struct node*`, so taking its address would yield a `struct node**` (a pointer-to-a-pointer to a `struct node`), and not a type matching the parameter declaration of `traversal()`.

That is to say in this case `head` is already of the correct type, you do not need to take its address, it already is an address.